# Why can I import successfully without __init__.py?

Tags: python, import

What exactly is the use of `__init__.py`? Yes, I know this file makes a directory into an importable package. However, consider the following example:

```
project/
   foo/
      __init__.py
      a.py
      bar/
         b.py
```

If I want to import `a` into `b`, I have to add following statement:

```
sys.path.append('/path_to_foo')
import foo.a
```

This will run successfully with or without `__init__.py`. However, if there is not an `sys.path.append` statement, a "no module" error will occur, with or without `__init__.py`. This makes it seem lik eonly the system path matters, and that `__init__.py` does not have any effect.

Why would this import work without `__init__.py`?

Comment: if you just do `import foo` python needs **something** to import, so it basically imports the `__init__` file of that folder.

Comment: You need `__init__.py` to do `import foo.bar`. It will act similar to `__init__` method on a class.

Comment: also, the `__init__.py` **is required to make it work** if you try just deleting the file then it will use the compiled `__init__.pyc` file probably located in a `__pycache__` subfolder, if you delete that as well then you will see that it is necessary.

Answer (score 27):

`__init__.py` has nothing to do with whether Python can find your package. You've run your code in such a way that your package isn't on the search path by default, but if you had run it differently or configured your `PYTHONPATH` differently, the `sys.path.append` would have been unnecessary.

`__init__.py` used to be necessary to create a package, and in most cases, you should still provide it. Since Python 3.3, though, a folder without an `__init__.py` can be considered part of an [implicit namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification), a feature for splitting a package across multiple directories.

> During import processing, the import machinery will continue to
>   iterate over each directory in the parent path as it does in Python
>   3.2. While looking for a module or package named "foo", for each directory in the parent path:
>
> - If `<directory>/foo/__init__.py` is found, a regular package is    imported and returned.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo.{py,pyc,so,pyd}` is found, a module is    imported and returned. The exact list of extension varies by platform 
>     and whether the -O flag is specified. The list here is 
>     representative.
> - If not, **but `<directory>/foo` is found and is a directory, it is    recorded** and the scan continues with the next directory in the parent 
>     path.
> - Otherwise the scan continues with the next directory in the parent    path.
>
> If the scan completes without returning a module or package, and **at
>   least one directory was recorded, then a namespace package is created.**

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: `__path__` gets built automatically. `__init__.py` isn't required for a namespace package, but a folder with an `__init__.py` will take priority over creation of a namespace package.

Comment: yes I realized that after reading further in the PEP, I added the relevant parts to your answer so other people don't have to search the document to find that part.

Answer (score 2):

> if I want to import a into b, I have to add following statement:

No! You'd just say: `import foo.a`. All this is provided you run the entire package  at once using `python -m main.module` where `main.module` is the entry point to your entire application. It imports all other modules, and the modules that import more modules will try to look for them from the root of this project. For instance, `foo.bar.c` will import as `foo.bar.b`

> Then it seems that only the system path matters and **init**.py does not have any effect.

You need to modify `sys.path` only when you are importing modules from locations that are not in your project, or the places where python looks for libraries. `__init__.py` not only makes a folder look like a package, it also does a few more things like "export" objects to outside world (`__all__`)

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to avoid `__init__.py` for some reason, you don't `sys.path`. Rather, create a module object and set its `__path__` to a list of directories.

Answer (score 1):

When you import something it has to either:

1. Retrieve an already loaded module or
2. Load the module that was imported

When you do `import foo` and python finds a folder called `foo` in a folder on your `sys.path` then it will look in that folder for an `__init__.py` to be considered the top level module.

(Note that if the package is not on your `sys.path` then you would need to `append` it's location to be able to import it.)

If that is not present it will look for a `__init__.pyc` version possibly in the `__pycache__` folder, if that is also missing then that folder `foo` is not considered a loadable python package. If no other options for `foo` are found then an `ImportError` is raised.

If you try deleting the `__init__.pyc` file as well you will see that the the initializer script for a package is indeed necessary.