# pip installing a package with the same namespace as a local package

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.6.5, installed via miniconda.  My issue is arising from the fact that I'm pip installing a package that has the same namespace as a local package.  After pip installing this package, I can no longer import from the local package.  I receive a `ModuleNotFoundError` error.  The namespaces need to stay this way, if possible.

Here is my directory structure:

```
/root
  stuff
    - __init__.py
    - my_stuff.py
  app.py
```

**init**.py

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

app.py

```
from stuff.my_stuff import my_fun
```

This works fine until I pip install the package with the same namespace, "stuff".  After pip installing the package, the import statement, `from stuff.my_stuff import my_fun` throws the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stuff.my_stuff'`.  I kind of understand why.  When importing modules in Python, it will look for built-in modules first, then sys.path, PYTHONPATH etc...

Here's the part thats really confusing me.  If I create another arbitrary local module, like `some_stuff`, as shown below:

```
/root
  stuff
    - __init__.py
    - my_stuff.py
  some_stuff
    - __init__.py
    - more_stuff.py
  app.py
```

and if I then run:

app.py

```
from some_stuff.more_stuff import more_fun
from stuff.my_stuff import my_fun
```

Everything works as expected.  i.e. if I import `some_stuff.more_stuff` before `stuff.my_stuff`, everything works.  But not vice versa.  Solely importing `stuff.my_stuff` causes the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

app.py

```
# The code above works, but this causes the error
from stuff.my_stuff import my_fun
```

What is causing this behaviour?  How can I solve this issue of locally referencing a package with the same namespace as one that was pip installed?

Edit:

I continued experimenting and noticed that when I remove all `__init__.py` files, everything works as expected.  I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974843/why-can-i-import-successfully-without-init-py):  Since Python 3.3, a folder without an `__init__.py` can be considered part of an implicit namespace package.  I'm still confused about the behaviour mentioned above though.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308293/how-to-install-python-package-with-a-different-name-using-pip#55817170

Answer (score 1):

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308293/how-to-install-python-package-with-a-different-name-using-pip#55817170) should answer your question

I am still putting the original answer here for convenience.

---

It's not possible to change "import path" (installed name) by specifying arguments to pip. You can, however, make some changes to the package after installing:

- use `pip install -e git+http://some_url#egg=some-name` that way even if both packages have the same import path, they will be saved under different directories (using some-name provided after #egg=). After this you can go to the source directories of packages (usually `venv/src/some-name`) and rename some folders to change import paths
- fork the repository, make changes, then install the package from that repository. Or you can publish your package on PyPI using different name and install it by that name
- use `pip download` to put one of the packages in your project, then rename folders as you like