# Use same name for a package as namespace package dependency

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.8.2, and I've created a namespaced package, called `fruit`. The structure of this namespaced package is as follows:

```
fruit
└── banana
    └── __init__.py
```

The `__init__.py` file here only contains `fruit="banana"`.

Note, I'm creating this package using implicit namespace packages (as per Python 3.3), and referring to the packages using `packages=find_namespace_packages(include=['fruit.banana', 'fruit.banana.*'])` in `setup.py`.

The issue I'm facing, occurs when using the dependency in a project that uses the same package naming. An example project structure of a project using the `fruit` dependency:

```
fruit --> top level package name
├── __init__.py
└── banana
    ├── __init__.py
    └── run.py
```

Both `__init__.py` files are empty, the contents of the `run.py` file are this:

```
from fruit.banana import fruit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fruit)
```

When running this `run.py`, I'm getting a `ImportError: cannot import name 'fruit' from 'fruit.banana' (/path/to/project/.../fruit/banana/__init__.py)`. However, when I change the package name marked with *top level package name* in the directory structure above to anything else than `fruit`, it runs fine.

How can I reuse the same package names when creating a namespaced package?

Comment: Related to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57857591

Comment: It seems that the "old" `pkgutil` style namespacing does work, but the new implicit namespacing doesn't. So when declaring something a namespace in both the dependency and the project using the dependency, it does work.