# Why is absolute import failing with Python 2, but succeeding with Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

While fiddling with Python import system, I noticed this form of absolute import works well with Python 3.6.8, but throws `ImportError` with Python 2.7.17. The package structure is as follows:

```
├── main8.py
├── pkg_a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mod7.py
│   ├── pkg_c
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── mod2.py
```

**main8.py**

```
import pkg_a.mod7
```

**pkg_a/mod7.py**

```
import pkg_a.pkg_c.mod2
```

**pkg_a/pkg_c/mod2.py**

```
print('Imported pkg_a.pkg_c.mod2')
```

If I execute `main8.py` with Python3, `pkg_a.pkg_c.mod2` gets imported successfully.

```
$ python3 main8.py 
Imported pkg_a.pkg_c.mod2
```

However, If I execute `main8.py` with Python2, it throws an `ImportError`.

```
$ python2 main8.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main8.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_a.mod7
  File "pkg_a/mod7.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_a.pkg_c.mod2
ImportError: No module named pkg_c.mod2
```

Adding `from __future__ import absolute_import` directive at the top of `main8.py` and `pkg_a/mod7.py` didn't help. Can anyone please explain why Python2 import is behaving like this?

Answer (score 1):

For Python2 you need to have a `__init__.py` next to `main8.py` to make a package:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── main8.py
└── pkg_a
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── mod7.py
    ├── mod7.pyc
    └── pkg_c
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        ├── mod2.py
        └── mod2.pyc

2 directories, 10 files
```

Running:

```
>> /usr/bin/python2.7 ./main8.py
Imported pkg_a.pkg_c.mod2

>> python3 ./main8.py
Imported pkg_a.pkg_c.mod2
```

Comment: What did change between Python 2 and Python 3 in this regard?

Comment: I dont know what was changed in Py3, having a init.py was always the way to create a package in Py2 and it is still stated in [Py3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974843/why-can-i-import-successfully-without-init-py